# Where does the prefix go in a command for a separable prefix verb?

Tags: word-order, separable-verb

I was wondering which was correct:

> Hör auf damit!

or

> Hör damit auf!

The Wikipedia page about [German sentence structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_sentence_structure) says:

> The separable prefix, if there is one, remains at its old place, separated.

So, I would think that the second one is correct.

However, when I do a Google search, both appear correct since they both pop up as suggestions.

Are they both correct, or did some people just type it into Google wrong?

Comment: Both are possible, but that’s not true in general. You could, e.g., say _Hör endlich auf!_, but _Hör auf endlich!_ isn’t grammatical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the same as with regular sentences. The unmarked case is that the detachable prefix goes to the end of the sentence:

> Hör damit auf.

Like the regular sentence:

> Ich höre damit auf.

As with regular sentences, constituents can be right-dislocated to the slot after the end verb/detachable prefix. That position is called [*Nachfeld*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nachfeld) in German grammar:

> Hör auf damit.

Like the regular sentence:

> Ich höre auf damit.